# How to insert parameter to regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have javascript file

this is part of the file

```
            a().initLibrary({

                            controls: [
                            "aa","bb"],
                            elements: []
            });
```

I want to check if input parameter is exist in controls for example

```
       var search1 = "dd" the result should be false
       var search2 = "aa" the result should be true
```

This is the regex to find the data in controls :

```
 controls\s*:\s*\[([^\]]*)  - the result is the data of the controls
```

How i can check if serach1 or serach2 exist in the result of regex without to check the result with string and split it according to ','.
Can I insert the parameter to the regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
controls\s*:\s*\[\s*((?=.*"bb").*?)\]
```

You can insert the parameter using lookahead See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/22 for `bb`.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/23 for `dd`

Comment: Can I pass it as parameter  and not "bb" in my case search1

Comment: how i can pass it is it ok controls\s*:\s*\[\s*((?=.*+ search1).*?)\]

Comment: is still not working I tried      var reDep = new RegExp("controls\s*:\s*\[\s*(?=.*"+newDependencey+").*?\s*\]"); i didn't get any result

Comment: @user1365697 when u apply this against the text string if there is not match .that shows that paramter is missing.also use delimiters for ur regex

Comment: I didn't understand could we have short chat ?